# Ordering system

Tags: java

I am stuck on the last part of this project. I have gotten all the other parts to work at least at the level that I need them to. I have it set up to where a customer can make selections about their product such as: type, color, material, and the number of the item they wish to order. Now I have to assign a price to the items. I do not want the type or color to affect the price only the material so it should be fairly simple. Once they select a price either paper or cardboard they will get the output message with their total cost (including tax). I have over looked something as I cannot even find a starting point as which to assign the costs to the item material selected. Below is the code that I have written, I am unsure how to add the portion I need. Any help would be great.

```
package pcos;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class pcos {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
        String openingMsg, nameInputMsg, customerName, nameOutputMsg,
            returnInputMsg, customerReturn, orderTypeMsg, customerType, returnOutputMsg, finalTotalAmt,
            orderColorMsg, customerColor, orderCoatMsg, customerCoat, itemAmountMsg, customerItemAmount, itemAmtOutptMsg, frameOutputMsg, greetingOutputMsg, outputMsg;
        //display opening message 
        openingMsg = "*** Welcome to the Diamond Playing Cards Online Ordering System ***\n"; 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, openingMsg);
        //get required input using dialog boxes
        nameInputMsg = "Enter your name: "; 
        customerName = getstringInput( nameInputMsg );
        returnInputMsg = "Have you ordered from us before (yes or no)? "; 
        customerReturn = getstringInput( returnInputMsg );
        orderTypeMsg = "What type of deck to you need Standard, Uno, Rook?";
        customerType = getstringInput(orderTypeMsg);
        orderColorMsg = "What color do you want your deck to be Red, Green, Blue, or Black?";
        customerColor = getstringInput(orderColorMsg);
        orderCoatMsg = "Do you prefer a clear laminate or a plastic coating on your cards?" + ".\n" + "Card coating     (Type)           Cost" + ".\n" + "                      Laminated         $2.00" + ".\n" +       "                     Plastic Coating     $2.50" ;
        customerCoat = getstringInput(orderCoatMsg);
        itemAmountMsg = "Please enter the number of your selected item you wish to purchase?" ;
        customerItemAmount =getstringInput(itemAmountMsg);

        //build output strings 
        nameOutputMsg = "Welcome " + customerName + ".\n";
        returnOutputMsg = "Your return customer status is " + customerReturn + ".\n";
        itemAmtOutptMsg= "You have slected to purchase " + customerItemAmount + ' ' + customerColor + ' ' + customerType + "(s)" +  " with " + customerCoat + " coating(s).\n"; ;
        finalTotalAmt= "The total cost of your purchase after taxes will be" + "\n";
        greetingOutputMsg = "     Thank you for visiting Diamond Playing Cards Online!" + "\n";
        //create output string 
        outputMsg = nameOutputMsg + returnOutputMsg + itemAmtOutptMsg + finalTotalAmt +greetingOutputMsg;
        //display output message
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, outputMsg );
        System.exit(0);
    }

    private static String getstringInput(String prompt){
        int count = 0;
        String input;
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( prompt );
        while ((input != null && input.length() == 0) && (count <2)){
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("No input was detected. \n" + prompt);
            count++;
        }
        if (count==2){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " You did not make an entry please try again later when you are ready to order.  ORDER TERMINATING.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return input;
    }
}
```

With the updates to the code it looks like this (though I decided to use double instead of float to keep things more accurate.   I am still having the issue of using the prices I have assigned.   I know I have to create some type of  expression but I cant figure out how to take the integer I get from the customers input * salesTax * cost of which ever type they select.  I Then I have to get it to display back to the user as in the outputMSG but that should be easy enough if I can just figure out the expression.

```
package pcos;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class pcos {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
        String openingMsg, nameInputMsg, customerName, nameOutputMsg,
            returnInputMsg, customerReturn, orderTypeMsg, customerType, returnOutputMsg, finalTotalAmt,
            orderColorMsg, customerColor, orderCoatMsg, customerCoat, itemAmountMsg, customerItemAmount, itemAmtOutptMsg, frameOutputMsg, greetingOutputMsg, outputMsg;
        //display opening message 
        openingMsg = "*** Welcome to the Diamond Playing Cards Online Ordering System ***\n"; 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, openingMsg);
        //get required input using dialog boxes
        nameInputMsg = "Enter your name: "; 
        customerName = getstringInput( nameInputMsg );
        returnInputMsg = "Have you ordered from us before (yes or no)? "; 
        customerReturn = getstringInput( returnInputMsg );
        orderTypeMsg = "What type of deck to you need Standard, Uno, Rook?";
        customerType = getstringInput(orderTypeMsg);
        orderColorMsg = "What color do you want your deck to be Red, Green, Blue, or Black?";
        customerColor = getstringInput(orderColorMsg);
        orderCoatMsg = "Do you prefer a clear laminate or a plastic coating on your cards?" + ".\n" + "Card coating     (Type)           Cost" + ".\n" + "                      Laminated         $2.00" + ".\n" +       "                     Plastic Coating     $2.50" ;
        customerCoat = getstringInput(orderCoatMsg);
        itemAmountMsg = "Please enter the number of your selected item you wish to purchase?" ;
        customerItemAmount =getstringInput(itemAmountMsg);
        Integer.parseInt(customerItemAmount);

        //build output strings 
        nameOutputMsg = "Welcome " + customerName + ".\n";
        returnOutputMsg = "Your return customer status is " + customerReturn + ".\n";
        itemAmtOutptMsg= "You have slected to purchase " + customerItemAmount + ' ' + customerColor + ' ' + customerType + "(s)" +  " with " + customerCoat + " coating(s).\n"; ;
        finalTotalAmt= "The total cost of your purchase after taxes will be" + "\n";
        greetingOutputMsg = "     Thank you for visiting Diamond Playing Cards Online!" + "\n";
        //create output string 
        outputMsg = nameOutputMsg + returnOutputMsg + itemAmtOutptMsg + finalTotalAmt +greetingOutputMsg;
        //display output message
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, outputMsg );
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static double typeLaminatePrice = 2.00;
    public static double typePlasticPrice = 2.50;
    public static double salesTaxRate = 0.10;
    double price;         
    if (customerFrame.equalsIgnoreCase("Plastic")) {
        price = typePlasticPrice;
    }else if (customerFrame.equalsIgnoreCase("Laminate")) {
        price = typeLaminatePrice;}  
    private static String getstringInput(String prompt){
        int count = 0;
        String input;
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( prompt );
        while ((input != null && input.length() == 0) && (count <2)){
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("No input was detected. \n" + prompt);
            count++;
        }
        if (count==2){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " You did not make an entry please try again later when you are ready to order.  ORDER TERMINATING.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return input;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use more data types than just String. As you are working with prices, the best primitive type is `float` and the best object is `BigDecimal`. For convenience, lets just work with floats:

You will want to add some values for the prices like this:

```
private static final float TYPE_LAMINATE_PRICE = 10.0f;
private static final float TYPE_PLASTIC_PRICE = 5.0f;
```

You then want a way to detect what the user entered, by doing something like:

```
float price;
if (customerCoat.equalsIgnoreCase("laminate") {
    price = TYPE_LAMINATE_PRICE;
} else if (customerCoat.equalsIgnoreCase("plastic") {
    price = TYPE_PLASTIC_PRICE;
}
```

You also need to detect the quantity needed. [Integer.parseInt(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) will do this for you.

This should get you started, I'm sure you'll be able to work out how to get things working how you want them from there.